# A value of type 'TextSpan' can't be returned from the method 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, widget

I need to create a custom SpanText, but i found this issue.
*A value of type 'TextSpan' can't be returned from the method 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget'.*

**The Code Is:**

```
class StareWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StareWidget({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  final String text;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextSpan();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html)

> To paint a TextSpan on a Canvas, use a TextPainter. To display a text span in a widget, use a RichText. For text with a single style, consider using the Text widget.

So your `TextSpan` needs to have a `RichText` as parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Refer TextSpan [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html)

Refer RichText [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

```
class StareWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StareWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String text;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        text: 'This is textspan ',
        children: <InlineSpan>[
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Widget in flutter',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
TextSpan buildTextSpan({required BuildContext context, TextStyle?style}) {
return TextSpan(
    style: style,
    text: 'your text one',
    children: const <TextSpan>[
    TextSpan(text: 'your text two'),
],);}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**